# Does the Flash slip on ice?

Tags: dc, the-flash

My question is inspired by a LEGO Justice League short, *Batman: Be-Leagured*. There's a scene where Flash is running towards Captain Cold, and Cold freezes the ground which causes Flash to slip.

I get that the show is geared towards kid humor, but I wonder if it's a strategy used by Flash's enemies *in the comics*.

**Is Flash susceptible to slippery surfaces while running at super speed?**

If not, is this as side-effect of his powers, or special boots?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes.

The character [Captain Cold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Cold) has 'cold guns' which have capabilities including:

- Creating a cold field where people and objects literally stop in their tracks. Cold uses this ability to slow down The Flash's movements.
- Creating a slippery field of ice which can slow down the Flash.

Here's an image from the comics:

[image: slip]

Not quite the comics, but here's a quote from the book [*Captain Cold's Arctic Eruption*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GRcb_CP2TfcC&pg=PT17&lpg=PT17&dq=captain+cold+the+flash+slip+on+ice&source=bl&ots=pt9PAFuPge&sig=9JxVmZq4-UCdaZvYvxOoaDklGlc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q6AEwA2oVChMI7aKiwbDbyAIVBUAaCh0agg8j#v=onepage&q=captain%20cold%20the%20flash%20slip%20on%20ice&f=false) (closer to canon than a LEGO Justice League short?) which shows him stopping the Flash with an ice field:

> Captain Cold cracked a wicked smile. He aimed his freeze gun again. Only this time, he lowered the muzzle and fired at the ground beneath Flash's feet.
>
> WHAM! **Flash slipped and fell hard onto the ice**.
>
> "Oh, did that hurt?" Captain Cold asked with a laugh. He raised his gun again and fired. BZZZZT!
>
> Flash tried to get up. The icy ground was so slippery he was running in place.

In fact it's also possible for the Flash to slip on natural ice, not just ice created especially to slow him down by Captain Cold's special guns. Earlier in the same book, he has to take precautions to avoid slipping:

> The higher the Flash climbed, the cooler the air became. Luckily, the super hero's vibrations created their own heat and kept him from getting cold. The ground was slippery in places. Snow and ice slowed him down. **He had to be very careful not to slip and fall.**

Comment: Haha. That faceplant is so stupid. I'm disappointed that he isn't immune! I'd think he'd move too fast for slipping issues to gain any traction (ba-dum ching). Or that the Speed Force would grant some immunity.

Comment: I don't *want* this to be the answer, and am hoping someone will show some more recent canon proving you wrong, but until then you can have the green tick mark.

Comment: @CreationEdge: I remember an older TV show where the Flash stumbled on marbles the evil guy spread over the street. That would imply that the marbles actually turned into deadly bullets, however, the truth is, from the point of interaction with his surroundings, the Flash seems to be a guy running at not-so-extraordinary speeds but having a fancy blurring effect while doing so.

Answer (score -1):

@CreationEdge Yes, Flash has slipped on Ice multiple times, and has difficulty running on it; he even says it's the reason he hates captain Cold so much. You need to accept the Speed Force does have limits and that there are ways of countering Flash's speed. Goin FASTER on ice make you more likely to slip, not less.

Comment: Could you provide some quotations/evidence-from-comics to support your answer?