# Captain Cold. What is so special about the cold gun?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

Talking here about the TV Show series of the Flash, I can't help but failing to see what is so special about the cold gun and whether it is just plot hole of whether there's something in the comics (or in the show) that justify people reaction to Captain Cold.

The gun, as described, only provides a freezing gun with limited range, limited burst power and nothing particularly special about it. One could argue a machine gun is way more dangerous both in terms of it effectiveness against the Flash (burst power alone increases the chance of at least one bullet hitting the target) and against others.

I fail to see the point of the episode where Cisco needs to provide a shield to the police to counter the effects of the cold gun instead of having the police just shoot from distance (I.e. Use a sniper and take him out). Same thing applies to the Flash himself, just super speed pass fast enough and take the gun away from him, if you can do it for a standard gun, why can't you with the Cold gun?

Is this just a plot hole or are there any additional powers in the comics not mentioned in the show?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105896/does-the-flash-slip-on-ice/105899#105899

Comment: With my Freeze Ray ... 
I will stop ... 
The world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [DC Comics Database](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Captain_Cold%27s_Cold_Gun) says this (emphasis mine):

> Captain Cold built a gun, based on a cyclotron, which emitted blasts of ice and cold. **It has the ability to cause the molecules of its target to reach absolute zero, causing molecules to stop moving.** The body can be re-animated with no damage to the subject by reactivating the molecules. This is different from Mr. Freeze's gun, which Cold considers sloppy, which somehow changes the chemical makeup of the victim to become ice.
>
> **The gun can also slow down areas of air, which Cold uses to put nets around to slow the Flash down when he attempts to run through.**

The big deal is its potential to slow the Flash down enough to make him vulnerable to attack by either cold blasts of the gun itself or by other means.

**In the comics, the gun generates a "cold field" that slows the Flash down enough for him to react before the Flash can take the gun:**

[image: cold field]

This isn't mentioned in the Flash TV show, to my knowledge. Probably because it's hokey and weird. The problem with NOT mentioning it is that there is now no explained reason to jump through so many ridiculous hoops to stop him.

To respond to your comment about the shields that Cisco provides, it makes more sense if you think of it as a replacement to standard body armor. Even though a bad guy with a gun can be taken out by snipers or a well-organized raid, doesn't it make sense to still provide them with body armor just in case it takes more time than anticipated for your sniper to get a good shot or something unexpected happens?

Comment: As conjecture, though, one might assume that the cold gun has a wider area of effect than what we see on the TV show which ends up providing a similar effect on Flash.  Still would have been nice of them to hang a lantern on it.

Comment: @joshbirk - That's a pretty viable theory I could get behind. It would allow them to basically give the same "cold field" theory without having to explain why the cold field doesn't freeze Snart. It's just a directional cold field!

Comment: Interestingly I just saw the first episode of "Young Justice" where Kid Flash does knock the gun away from him ... but only after both him and Flash are running circles around him to distract him.  So there seems to be a common theme of "can't run right at him".